# Junit Ant Task, output stack trace

Tags: java, ant, build-process, junit

I have a number of tests failing in the following JUnit Task.

```
 <target name="test-main" depends="build.modules" description="Main Integration/Unit tests">
        <junit fork="yes"
               description="Main  Integration/Unit Tests"
               showoutput="true"
               printsummary="true"
               outputtoformatters="true">
            <classpath refid="test-main.runtime.classpath"/>
            <batchtest filtertrace="false" todir="${basedir}">
                <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="**/*Test.class" excludes="**/*MapSimulationTest.class"/>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

How do I tell Junit to ouput the errors for each test so that I can look at the stack trace and debug the issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was to add the  tag within the  tag.

```
 <target name="test-main" depends="build.modules" description="Main Integration/Unit tests">
        <junit fork="yes"
               description="Main  Integration/Unit Tests"
               showoutput="true"
               printsummary="true"
               outputtoformatters="true">
            <classpath refid="test-main.runtime.classpath"/>
            <batchtest filtertrace="false">
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/out/test/common" includes="**/*Test.class" excludes="**/*MapSimulationTest.class"/>
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/out/test/test-simulation" includes="**/*Test.class" excludes="**/*MapSimulationTest.class"/>
            </batchtest>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 18):

You'll need to add the formatter task as a child of the batchtest task (NOT as the immediate child of the junit task)

The syntax of formatter is:

```
<formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
```

`type` can be one of `plain`, `brief`, `xml` or `failure`.

`usefile="false"` asks Ant to send output to the console.

Scroll down to the h4 on "formatters" at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html for more details.

Comment: At least with ant 1.9.0, you can also add the formatter as a child of the junit task.  That would be helpful if you have several batch tasks.